# Vue 3 - Attaching a prop to an @input to update a store

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The idea I'm trying to figure out is that the Input.vue component has access to the personalInfo store which contains a name, email, and phone. That's already hooked up to the validation.js so when any of the three inputs fails validation, the labels update correctly from the errors store.

I can't, however, get the personalInfo store to correctly wire up to the input values. I thought having @input="personalInfo.props.value = $event.target.value" would use the value prop to fill in the blank for personalInfo."..." but that doesn't work. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'value')"

I also tried putting an :input attribute on the <Input ... /> component as :input="personalInfo.name = $event.target.value" (as well as .email and .phone in place of .name) but that also didn't work.

The goal is to take the values from the three inputs, update the personalInfo store correctly with the input values, if there's an error update the errors store (which does work when there is an error, but does not yet reset the error store to an empty object when the error is fixed).

Here's the three inputs

```
   <Input value="name" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Stephen King">{{
                errors.name ? errors.name : "Name"
            }}</Input>

            <Input
                value="email"
                type="email"
                placeholder="stephenking@lorem.com"
                >{{ errors.email ? errors.email : "Email" }}</Input
            >

            <Input value="phone" type="tel" placeholder="+1 234 567 890">{{
                errors.phone ? errors.phone : "Phone Number"
            }}</Input>
```

The Input.vue component

```
<template>
    <label
        :for="props.value"
        class="text-marine-blue text-xs font-bold mt-3 md:mt-5"
        id="name-label"
        ><slot></slot
    ></label>
    <input
        :type="props.type"
        :id="props.value"
        class="border-2 p-2 rounded-md mt-1"
        :placeholder="props.placeholder"
        @input="personalInfo.props.value = $event.target.value"
    />
</template>

<script setup>
import { personalInfo } from "../../store/store";

const props = defineProps(["value", "placeholder", "type"]);
</script>
```

The store

```
export const personalInfo = reactive({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: "",
});

export const errors = reactive({ name: "", email: "", phone: "" });
```

validation.js

```
import { personalInfo } from "../store/store";
import { errors } from "../store/store";

export const personalInfoValidation = () => {
    Object.assign(errors, { name: "", email: "", phone: "" });

    if (personalInfo.name !== "") {
    } else {
        errors.name = "Name - Please enter a valid name";
    }

    if (
        /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(personalInfo.email)
    ) {
    } else {
        errors.email = "Email - Please enter a valid email";
    }

    if (
        /^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im.test(
            personalInfo.phone
        )
    ) {
    } else {
        errors.phone = "Phone - Please enter a valid phone number";
    }

};
```

Comment: `personalInfo` has no `props` value.  It only has what you've defined in your store.  `@input="personalInfo.props.value` should just be `@input="personalInfo.name`...  "_I also tried putting an :input attribute_" that didn't work because `input` isn't an attribute, it's an event, and for events you use `@` to listen to them like in your original (and almost correct) attempt.

Comment: There should be a personalInfo.name, personalInfo.email, and personalInfo.phone though, which is why I tried "personalInfo.props.value" with "props.value" filling in for name, email, and phone from the Input component's value attribute

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now.  The problem is the syntax `personalInfo.props.value` which expects a property on the personalInfo object literally called "props", whereas you're trying to access a property _dynamically_ where the property key is equal to the value of `props.value`.  In that case, the syntax you want is `@input="personalInfo[props.value]`

Comment: Just FYI, you cannot update a prop as they are not meant to be changed. For example, you cannot pass a prop to a child component and then modify that value within the child component as the parent component that the prop came from will not be updated.